# How to set random backgroundImage through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the html body background image after clicking a button. The images are stored in img folder. When I give hardcode URL in JavaScript then it works but when it is a variable then it does not work.

```js
let frame_set = [
  'img/1.jpg',
  'img/2.jpg',
  'img/3.jpg',
  'img/4.jpg',
  'img/5.jpg',
  'img/6.jpg'

]

function next() {
  let frame_color = Math.floor((Math.random() * (frame_set).length));
  let url_p = '"url(\'' + frame_set[frame_color] + '\')"';
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = url_p;
}
```

```html
hello world
<button id="next" onclick="next()">  Next background </button>
```

Comment: You are not skipping the commas correctly in the file path.

Comment: You're creating a quoted string rather than a string, to set the background image to. You don't need the extra `"`s at the beginning and end of `url_p`.

Comment: `let url_p = \`url('${frame_set[frame_color]}')\`;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like this---

```js
function next(){
  let frame_color=Math.floor((Math.random() * (frame_set).length));
  let url_p="url(\"" + frame_set[frame_color] + "\")";
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = url_p;
}
```

Try this 
hope it works 
All the Best!

Comment: Thank you for tagging best answer I am happy to help you